# Новый проект на gulp

Tags: gulp, npm

Что нужно написать в консоли чтобы **gulp** установил все нужные пакеты?
`package.json` и `gulpfile.js` уже есть

```
{
 "name": "myproj",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
   "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
   "del": "^2.2.2",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
   "gulp-cache": "^0.4.5",
   "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
   "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
   "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
   "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
   "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
   "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
   "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.0"
 }
}
```

Посмотрел видео уроки, везде говорят, что просто копируются два этих файла и потом пишется `npm up` то есть обновить все пакеты.
Почему не `npm install` ? Когда я ввожу `npm up` у меня выводит ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не силен в понимании таких ошибок, подскажите в чем проблема.
и расскажите в чем отличия `devDependencies` и `dependencies` когда нужно писать пакеты `devDependencies` а когда в `dependencies`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам `gulp` ничего не ставит. Установкой пакетов занимается [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

По Вашей ошибке.

Для начала, обновите `nodejs` и пакетный менеджер `npm`. На скриншоте видно, что они у Вас далеко не последних версий. Затем можно попробовать сделать:

`npm cache clear`

И смотреть, что будет дальше.

По разнице `devDependencies/dependencies`.

В `devDependencies` располагаются пакеты, которые требуются для разработки (например, тот же `gulp`). Эти пакеты на продакшене не нужны, поэтому и пишутся в это секцию.

В `dependencies` же заносятся пакеты, от которых зависит непосредственно работа приложения.

Соответственно, чтобы при установке пакета занести его в `dependencies` ставим ключ `--save`:

```
npm install <пакет> --save
```

Чтобы записать в `devDependencies`, используем `--save-dev`

```
npm install <пакет> --save-dev
```

Comment: "обновите nodejs и пакетный менеджер npm". А какие команды правильно писать для обновления?

Comment: Для `windows`, вроде самое адекватное будет [скачать](https://nodejs.org/) с оф. сайта последнюю версию и переустановить. Затем, для проверки версий введите `node -v` и `npm -v` соответственно.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо, еще маленький вопрос, обязательно ли ставить самые последние версии пакетов sass к примеру и другие

Comment: Это уже дело вкуса. Лучше, для начала,  наверно - да. Если будут возникать какие-то трудности с версиями, то всегда можно поставить пакет с необходимой версией, например: `npm install gulp@3.9.1`

Comment: а как поставить предпоследнюю версию, чтоб отсекать ошибок  с бета версиями пакетов, или бета версии не считаются как последние